# Content not being Posted properly?

Tags: php, simpletest

I am using simpleTest WebBrowser for DataScraping on this URL http://www.magicbricks.com/bricks/agentSearch.html.  But though everything seems right I always get the error `City Field is required`. I guess the problem might be with the fact that values in city field changes dynamically when value of State changes. Any solutions?  Here is my code.

```
<?php
require_once('simpletest/browser.php');

$browser = &new SimpleBrowser();
$browser->addHeader('User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2');
$browser->get('http://www.magicbricks.com/bricks/agentSearch.html');
$browser->setField('source','agentSearch');
$browser->setField('_transactionType','1');
$browser->setField('_propertyType','1');
$browser->setField('resultPerPage','50');
$browser->setField('agentSearchType','B');
$browser->setField('state','520');
$browser->setField('city','4320');
$browser->setField('keyword','');
$browser->setField('country','50');

print $browser->submitFormById('searchFormBean');
print $browser->getResponseCode()

?>
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want to do a `POST` instead of a `GET`? See here for a demo: http://www.simpletest.org/en/form_testing_documentation.html#raw (EDIT: Ok, I see you're trying to submit the form, but it's drawing the lists dynamically for the two selects.)

Comment: see that there are two functions being called with event onChange on that select element for city: <select id="city" name="city" onchange="onCityChange();cityFunction('city','localityName','suggest')" size="1"> . try to figure out what is it doing

Comment: @jared: Yes, but I can't repeat the same. When state variable is selected some strange content gets posted and I cant replicate the same. @ Pabluez: Just too hard to find where those functions are defined.

Comment: Are you using Firebug or Chrome Console Net tab to view the requests that populate those dropdowns? My guess is you'll need to pull those lists in (first state, then city) and iterate over them in PHP.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Doesn't help much. I replicated the same request using Post function I get the error "'The specified call count is not a number'" as a DWR reply

Comment: If you've just replaced `->get(` with `->post(` in the code above, that won't work; you'll need to rewrite it. If you're trying to pull the search results for each state-city, you'll have to get the data for the selects (if simpleTest won't do it dynamically for you).

Comment: A better question at this point (maybe *another* question) is, "Does simpleTest handler dynamic content loading for source pages?" You're not dealing with a standard form submit, since the state and city select options require a dynamic, asynchronous request to populate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some errors i noticed

Field Missing

1. Missing agentSearchType field
2. Missing transactionType  ( There is Both transactionType & _transactionType)
3. missing propertyType ( There is both propertyType & _propertyType)

There are some header information you need to add such as

1. Referer
2. Cookie

A typical post test should come this format if you view the headers

```
        POST http://www.magicbricks.com/bricks/agentSearch.html HTTP/1.1
        Host: www.magicbricks.com
        Connection: keep-alive
        Content-Length: 173
        Cache-Control: max-age=0
        Origin: http://www.magicbricks.com
        User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.79 Safari/535.11
        Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
        Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
        Referer: http://www.magicbricks.com/bricks/agentSearch.html
        Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
        Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
        Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
        Cookie: JSESSIONID=nF1UqV3DM2tZC42zByYm6Q**.MBAPP09; __utma=163479907.1423216630.1331970312.1331970312.1331970312.1; __utmb=163479907.1.10.1331970312; __utmc=163479907; __utmz=163479907.1331970312.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); _mbRunstats=3k0ilrpcgprh4tea

        source=agentSearch&agentSearchType=B&country=51&state=601&city=8417&transactionType=11951&_transactionType=1&propertyType=10001&_propertyType=1&keyword=tesy&resultPerPage=50
```

I hope this helps

:D